# mysqli returns true for INSERT query, row not inserted

Tags: php, mysql, insert, mysqli

```
 if ($word != '' && $text != '') {
    $result = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM variables WHERE `word` = '$word'");
    if ($source = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $conn->query("UPDATE variables SET `text` = '$text' WHERE `word` = '$word'");
        echo 0;
    } else {
        if ($result = $conn->query("INSERT INTO variables (`word`, `text`) VALUES ('$word', '$text')"))
            echo 1;
    }
}
```

The above is the INSERT code (and update) the UPDATE code works fine, however when the INSERT query is called the query returns `true` but when i check the data, it hasn't been inserted.

Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance.

EDIT:

variables table structure:

```
`word` varchar(100) NOT NULL, //also PRIMARY KEY
`text` text NOT NULL
```

Comment: and it displays `0` ? What is $source ?

Comment: no that's the UPDATE query (echoed to an ajax call which i need to create an element only if the data is new not updated), the INSERT query returns true for the `if` statement and echoes `1`, but no data is inserted into the database.

Comment: $conn is mysqli or pdo??

Comment: the tag `mysqli` should give it away

Comment: Did you many to solve this problem at all? I have the same thing, just moved my DBs from a linux server to Windows now my insert queries don't work, they return true but no data is added. One strange thing though is after trying to do the insert query the 'overhead' section in the table structure turns red. If you have solved the problem please let me know how? Thanks @CKKiller

Comment: @ragebunny Yup, this was in a switch statement (the rest of which seemed unnecessary) but what caused it was a missing `break;` on the case... And the case after just happened to be for deleting the row from the table. So my query was successful, then so was the deleting query following :/

Answer (score 1):

You have a single `=` in an `if` condition.

maybe you wanted:

```
if ($result->num_rows){ // see if there are any rows
    $conn->query("UPDATE variables SET `text` = '$text' WHERE `word` = '$word'");
    echo 0;
} else {
    $conn->query("INSERT INTO variables (`word`, `text`) VALUES ('$word', '$text')");
    echo 1;
}
```

tested:

```
$conn = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'test');
$word = 'word1';
$text = 'text1';

$result = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM variables WHERE `word` = '$word'");
if ($result->num_rows){
    $conn->query("UPDATE variables SET `text` = '$text' WHERE `word` = '$word'");
    echo 0;
} else {
    $conn->query("INSERT INTO variables (`word`, `text`) VALUES ('$word', '$text')");
    echo 1;
}
```

Comment: what I wrote does exactly what you want, it check if there are result in database based on first query, if there are it makes update, if no it inserts. Now I don't know if your insert query is correct.

Comment: It calls the correct query (as it did before, show by the echoed numbers) and the INSERT query is executed and returns `true`, but no data is actually put in the database, no errors (even using `$conn->error`) and the connection details are correct as I've used them elsewhere in other scripts that work completely fine.

Comment: your first code wasn't ok, can you add to question your `variables` table structure?

Comment: are you sure the `$word` variable is set ok ?

Comment: `$word` variable is 'test' (echoed correctly `echo $word`)

`$text` variabe is 'auto' (echoed correctly `echo $text`)

Comment: I don't understand, really .. what can be wrong .. let me test

Comment: I don't either :/ , SELECT query works, inserting using the phpMyAdmin works, but using the mysql query string from the phpMyAdmin doesn't even work...

Comment: I've pasted my tested code, works without any problems. Updates if `word` exists or inserts if it doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1):

I've been struggling with the same problem but solved it in a different way.

Check how many rows are affected, like this (this example uses mysqli but I hope you'll get the point):

```
$number_of_rows_affected = mysqli_affected_rows($conn);
```

If $number_of_rows_affected = 0 then INSERT wasn't working. A number larger than 0 means a successful INSERT.

Answer (score -2):

Not sure why you use backticks around 'word' and 'text' in your query.
For debugging this, I write the query to a string and print it before executing it, to make sure the query is what I wanted, so use:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO variables (`word`, `text`) VALUES ('$word', '$text')"
print("$query")
if ($result = $conn->query($query))
        echo 1;
```

Are you sure the insert does not work? Do you close your database connection before you check, maybe the results have just not been committed to your database when you check?

Comment: i get `INSERT INTO variables (`word`, `text`) VALUES ('test', 'auto')1` as a result from that, how it should be but no data inserted. I'm checking this via phpMyAdmin (refreshing each time to make sure)

Comment: in another thread someone just said that backticks do not work with data. Don't know if that's the reason, but I propose to avoid them

Comment: and as you have phpMyAdmin: try the INSERT with backticks and with single quotes, just do it manually. Does that make the difference?